# How to load Nodejs code into script file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am trying to load the code from my server file(code written in node.js,express.js)
into my script file.
When i console.log the identifier that i have used for importing nodejs code ,
nothing is shown in browser.
And I don't even see there's an error

```
***nodejs code :*** 
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");


const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get('/my-courses', (req, res) => {
    res.render('user-courses', {foo: 'hello'});
  });

// your courses section
const todaysDate = new Date();


  let userCourses = [
    {
     //some code
    },
    {
     //code
    }
  ];

  module.exports = userCourses;

 
app.listen("3000", ()=>{
    console.log("server running on 3000");
});

  ***[my script file code :][1]*** 
  const userCourses = require("/app");
  console.log(userCourses);
```

Comment: You can't. The frontend doesn't have access to backend modules. You have to provide the data in your backend and load it in your frontend, e.g. with AJAX.

Comment: thanks @jabaa i figured it out using EJS